# Facebook Events: Not returning events

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

**TL;DR:** I want to read the events off of a public page, and display them on our non-profit's website. Net-net: we do not have to duplicate event creation in both facebook, and our google calendar we currently use.

I am making the following api call:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/DurangoCafeAuPlay/events?access_token=${APP_ID}|${APP_SECRET}
```

It returns with an empty array: `[]`

When I go to the page, I can clearly see events are occuring today.

The app I created is independent of the page, which was created by someone else, but i am listed with the admin role on that facebook Page.

these calls are going to be coming from my node server, so the appid and app secret would never be given to a client browser....

**update** i was able to use the graph api explorer to generate a user token that i then had to grant page permissions for a page token. this token does return data, contrary to @misorude comment below.

That said, here's what i need to know in pure rest format:
1) how do i get a user token via the url? I tried the following code, but all i get back is the `appid|secret` value returned, which I already have

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=${process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials`;
```

Comment: did you try with a page token?

Comment: I want to access these events anonomously, like i can using a standard browser window.... not sure why this is so particularly hard.... here is the events page i want to programatically look at. https://www.facebook.com/pg/DurangoCafeAuPlay/events/?ref=page_internal

Comment: you are listed as admin, so try it with a page token.

Comment: There’s a big fat note right on the top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events, saying _“This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.”_

Comment: that message does not make sense... why is it even in the API? Why can i, and an anonymous user in a browser access the event data via a web crawler rather than via an API. It makes no sense.

Comment: I am an admin of the page, but the page was created by someone else. I cannot for what ever reason make a call to get a page token. this security is bass ackwards.